# .animate width on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have an issue with a logo i'm trying to show at a set point on scroll. Currently .animate is delaying for a couple of seconds before showing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d615hbLL/)

No idea why it seems to be doing this as with

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() > 575 ) {
    $("#small-logo").show('slow');
}
else {
    $("#small-logo").hide('slow');
}
});
```

It seems to be [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/d615hbLL/) when set to "display:none" however I want to use jQuery Easing Plugin to make the animation nicer.

Comment: Quick fix (but buggy) is to add a `.stop()` before each `.animate`. Else you need a flag since animation queue on each scroll event.

Comment: binding to your scroll event is going to flood the clients computer with events you should singularly with a set timeout

Comment: @johnny5 how would I do that? Thanks

Comment: @BN83 here's a link describing the issue and how to fix it http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 250 ) {
        $("#small-logo").animate( { "width": "200"}, {queue: false} );
    }
    else {
        $("#small-logo").animate( { "width": "0"}, {queue: false}  );
    }
});
```

Here's the documentation on queue: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's animate function has a default animation time of 400ms (0.4 seconds) either for making your logo big and again 400ms for making it small.

You could adjust that speed with a parameter:

```
$("#small-logo").animate( { "width": "200"}, 100 );
```

100 stands there for 100ms per animation.

Edit:
The answer from rodes works like a charm!